# Random spacing is being added in PHP files when editing

Tags: php

I'm not exactly sure when this started, but as of late all of my PHP files have been suffering a rather annoying issue where a blank space is being added to the end of every single line. A bit annoying, but not altogether impossible to work with/around. However, I've also noticed that when code afflicted with this issue is copied and pasted elsewhere, these innocuous spaces being new, blank lines which is a rather big problem.

I have noticed that opening afflicted files, and re-saving them with UTF-8 NO BOM seems to correct the issue until the file is closed and reopened later. I've run all of my files through a program that changes files to be NO BOM, but it didn't seem to have any affect at all.

I'm wondering if this is an issue with the editor I use (UltraEdit), file settings on the computer/local server, an issue with the ftp program (FileZilla) or even a problem with the web server.

Comment: Try using a different editor like notepadd++ or something simple to rule this out as more than likely this is the issue.

Comment: Would be good to know info about the server you are using as UnskilledFreak suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of your problem is the transfer between a Windows system (your workstation) and a Linux system (your web server) using FTP. For text files, you should use the ASCII (or text) mode (not the "binary" mode) of the FTP program when transferring files in both ways.
Transferring it using the binary mode is also ok. What produces your problem is the mix of them.

Windows uses two characters (CR and LF) to mark the end of the lines in a text file. Linux (and OSX and other Unix-es) uses only LF for this purpose. The text/ascii transfer mode of the FTP programs does the appropriate conversion on transfer. The binary mode do not alter the files it transfers.

This is what happens: you create a file on Windows. Its lines end with CR LF. You transfer it on Linux using binary mode. The CR characters are not removed. They are not visible on the web page but they are displayed (as ^M) by some Linux programs. They are just at the end of each line. You probably modify the script on your webserver to quick fix an issue you found when you put the page live then you transfer the file back but, this time, using the text transfer mode. Or maybe a friend/workmate copies the file on their own Windows computer and they use a different FTP program with different settings than yours. Because of the text mode, before each NL character the FTP program inserts a new CR character. This makes the lines ending with CR CR LF. Some Windows programs display the first CR character as a space. Others consider it as a new line (even if it is just "half" of a new line).

It has nothing to do with the UTF-8 BOM. Btw, UTF-8 BOM is completely useless.

I cannot tell about UltraEdit but [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org), [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com) and other Windows editors detect and display in their status bar the type of the new lines in the file they edit (Windows or Linux). They also allow the user to change the type of the new lines from one system to another.

The solution is very simple: after you fix the newlines configure your FTP client to use text transfer mode for PHP files (and other text files). Also teach your coworkers how to set their programs to do the same.

Comment: I messed around with a couple of settings involved with the transfer of files between the local server and the web server to account for this Windows/Linux conflict, and that seems to have solved the issue. Might have to tinker with the settings a bit more to make sure it's transferring 100% correctly, but otherwise this put me on the right path to solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the file editor.

Downlaod Notepad++ and set character to UTF-8 Without BOM and save it.

Edit:

Set file permission to read-only.

Comment: OP: "I have noticed that opening afflicted files, and re-saving them with UTF-8 NO BOM seems to correct the issue until the file is closed and reopened later. I've run all of my files through a program that changes files to be NO BOM, but it didn't seem to have any affect at all."